# Using Dart 2.17 Super Initializer for Widget key

Tags: flutter, dart

Now that Dart 2.17 allows for the super initializer feature it seems that I can now replace my default boilerplate

```
class WidgetName extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

with

```
class WidgetName extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetName({super.key});
```

What are the ramifications of this? I assume this change in code isn't 100% equivalent given the possible nullable value of key in the 'old' syntax vs the 'new'. Or maybe I don't fully comprehend the underlying process of super initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 100% equivalent. In both cases `key` is of type `Key?`.

You can confirm what the type of `key` is when you hover over the constructor in your editor.

[image: super initializer tooltip]

The type of a super initializer will match what the type is in the super constructor. The super constructor in this case is the default constructor for [StatelessWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget/StatelessWidget.html) which is defined as `const StatelessWidget({Key? key})`.